# What is the dimension of a complex Stiefel manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, stiefel-manifolds

The Stiefel manifold is defined as follows.
\begin{equation}
V_{k}(\mathbb{C}^{n})  = \big\{
X \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times k} | X^{*} X = I_{k} 
\big\}
\end{equation}
where $n \geqslant k \geqslant 1$.

According to the pulic knowledge on Wikipedia on "Steifel manfiold", the dimension of manifold
is given by
\begin{equation}  
\operatorname{dim} V_{k}(\mathbb{C}^{n}) = 2nk -k^{2} \;.  
\end{equation}

Actually, the above dimension is only correct when $V_{k}(\mathbb{C}^{n})$ is considered a real manifold embedded in a $2nk$-dimensional real vector space $\mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$.

More naturally, the vector space $\mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$ should be considered as complex rather than real, and the dimension of the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$ is $nk$ rather than $2nk$.

If the manifold $V_{k}(\mathbb{C}^{n}) $ is considered as complex rather than real, the dimension, given by Wikipedia, I contend, is not correct.

I can not find useful information on the complexification of $V_{k}(\mathbb{C}^{n})$.

I also content, for example, when $k=1$, there is not such a thing as the complex Stiefel manifold, only real Stiefel manifold exists.

Under what condition, a complex Stiefel manifold exists?

What is the original source giving the resulf $\operatorname{dim} V_{k}(\mathbb{C}^{n}) = 2nk -k^{2}\,$?
Is there anybody who can help?

Comment: What do you mean by "complexification of $V_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$"? The manifold $V_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is a real submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^{n \times k}$. For example, like you mentioned, when $k = 1$ then $V_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ can be identified with $S^{2n - 1}$ which is an odd (real) dimensional sphere do it definitely doesn't have a structure of a complex manifold (which must be of even real dimension).

Comment: As to the formula for the dimension, if you consider the map $F$ from $C^{n \times k}$ to the subspace of self-adjoint $k \times k$ matrices then $V_k(\mathbb{C}^n) = F^{-1}(I_k)$ and $I_k$ is a regular value of $F$ so $\dim V_k(\mathbb{C}^n) = 2nk - k^2$.

Comment: Given a point  $X \in V_{k}(\mathbb{C}^{n}) $, one can have the tangent space  and normal space at $X$.  A random vector $Z \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$ can be projected onto the tangent space and normal space. Let $Z_{T}$ and $Z_{N}$ be the non-trivial projections of $Z$. I would like to have the tangent space and normal space be complex rather than be real. If the range space and normal space can be complex,  one should have $tr\, (Z_{T})^{H}  Z_{N}  = 0$.  I call that the complexification of the Stiefel manifold.  Is  $tr\, (Z_{T})^{H}  Z_{N}  = 0$ possible?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are asking when the (real) tangent space of $V_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is a complex vector subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{n \times k}$. This never happens. Consider the point $X \in V_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ whose columns are the first $k$ elements of the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$. The tangent space at $X$ is $T_{X}(V_k(\mathbb{C}^n)) = \{ V \in M_{n \times k}(\mathbb{C}) \, | \, V + V^{*} = 0 \}$ and this is never a complex vector subspace (if $V \in T_X(V_k(\mathbb{C}^n))$ then $V^{*} = -V$ but $(iV)^{*} = -i(-V) = iV$ so $iV$ is not in the tangent space).

Comment: If the tangent space can not be complex. To define the orthogonality between two vectors $A$ and $B$ respectively in the tangent space and normal space, the elegant inner product $tr A^{H} B$ usually used for the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}^{n×k}$ had to be abandoned. If that is the situation, an inner product for real space has to be adopted. I wonder the inner product for the $2nk$-dimensional real space $\mathbb{C}^{n×k}$ will look awkward.

Comment: Let $A = A_1 + i \cdot A_2 \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$ where $A_1 = real(A)$ and $A_2 = imag(A)$ and $B = B_1 + i \cdot B_2 \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$. The inner product is something like this ---- $ \langle A, B \rangle = tr(A_1^{T} B_1) + tr(A_2^{T} B_2)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119492/discussion-between-liang-liao-and-levap).